# Basic fluid - inflow too small to generate fluid or generated fluid too thick

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm setting up a fluid simulation, and it seems like inflow is too small to generate any fluid, or generated fluid too thick(too much).

This is the setting of the simulation:

Inflow
Volume Initialization: Shell
Export Animated Mesh: Checked
Inflow Velocity: Y -200

Domain
Final Resolution: 200
Preview: 100
Time Start: 0
End: 32
Speed: 1

Outflow (2 outflows)
Export Animated Mesh: Unchecked

Scene gravity: Y -2, Z -9.8

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3i7j83qifddrfnt/water_simul_new.blend?dl=0

I'm making a simulation of about 32 seconds, and I'd like to make fluid to wave slowly through y-axis.

**I found out inflow object is too small to generate anything(no fluid at all or fluid stuck in outflow object) or generates too much fluid after I scale up the object (scale applied well).**

Settings are always mostly similar. I'm only controlling inflow object's scale or Final Resolution.

Is there any way I can make small fluid coming forward from far away? Right now the blend file shows too many fluids.

Thank you!

Comment: the blend file doesn't work, i believe you can upload directly

Answer (score 0):

Setting your y-axis inflow to -200 is a substantially large number for fluid physics. Try something like 2 or 3, because large numbers cannot be calculated, and don't show up. This is probably why your simulation is failing.